# Xcode Project Settings Preventing TabBar at Bottom of iPhone X Models?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-x

I have an old project that I've been working on and off on for about 4 years now - the project has gone through many upgrades of XCode versions from 6 to 10 (I'm now using XCode 10.2.1 with 12.2 SDK). The main problem I'm having with it is that it utilizes a Tab View Controller to switch tabs, and **no matter what I do, I cannot get the tab bar to appear on the bottom of an iPhone X family device correctly: it appears much higher than it should**.

To try and finally narrow down the problem, I've essentially temporarily "replaced" all code and storyboard items from the project to see if *anything* will move the tab bar to where it's supposed to (if I just create a blank new project with a tab bar controller, the tab bar does appear where it should). I created a test storyboard with just a Tab Bar Controller going to one navigation controller (no constraints have been put in). There is no viewController codes attached to them. I've replaced the app delegate with a "blank" app delegate so there are essentially no extraneous code or restraints there at all. And I still get the tab bar moved:

[image: iphone xs simulator]

This happens on the simulator and the device, and there is no code or storyboard setting that's doing this (this same setup on a new project puts the tab bar in the right place).

I've looked around in the Build Settings and other properties that I may have missed to see if I constrained something years ago that may affect this, and didn't see anything.

**Is there anything I should be looking for in the project settings that would do this?**

I don't want to rebuild the project in a new project - there are many linked libraries, certificates, cocoapods, storyboard items, and I know it would be horrible to try and put it all back in one piece.

My Deployment Target is set to iOS 11, Devices: iPhone, Base SDK: iOS

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (adding that the navigation bar is also dropping down from where it should be, which is happening in the real project as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by not having a correct launch image for the iPhone X. The easiest way to fix this is to tell the app target not to use launch images (from the app bundle or from the asset catalog) but to use the *LaunchScreen.storyboard* instead. (If you don't have one, make one; be sure to set it as a launch screen storyboard by clicking Use As Launch Screen and configure your target to point to it. Examine a plain vanilla new project to see what I mean.) You might not want to keep things that way in the long term but at least it will allow your app to launch to the correct size on all devices.

Comment: OMG that did it! Wow, I never would have guessed (**stares at Apple**) - thank you. You said that wasn't a permanent solution - what is the danger in keeping the splash screen as a VC?

Comment: Oh, no danger. It’s what I do. I merely meant that your project doesn’t use one now, implying that you don’t like them. So I was just saying that even you don’t like the launch storyboard, you should try this solution just to prove to yourself that this was the issue.